# Installing Saxonica EE 1.2.1 building PHP modules produces C++ build errors

Tags: php, debian, saxon, saxon-c

When running `./configure --enable-saxon` in folder `~/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API`, that's success, 
next command `sudo make` is the place where interesting stuff happends, i get some errors, written down below.

Doing same stuff with Saxon HE 1.2.1 worked like a sharm, am i missing something?

```
/bin/bash /root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/libtool --mode=compile g++  -I. -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/include -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/main -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/jni  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/php7_saxon.cpp -o php7_saxon.lo 
libtool: compile:  g++ -I. -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/include -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/main -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/jni -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/php7_saxon.cpp  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/php7_saxon.o
/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/php7_saxon.cpp:20:1: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to â€˜char*â€™ [-Wwrite-strings]
 };
 ^
/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/php7_saxon.cpp:20:1: warning: ISO C++ forbids converting a string constant to â€˜char*â€™ [-Wwrite-strings]
/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/php7_saxon.cpp: In function â€˜void zim_Xslt30Processor_callFunctionReturningValue(zend_execute_data*, zval*)â€™:
/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/php7_saxon.cpp:1664:29: warning: NULL used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
         if(Z_TYPE_P(val) != NULL) {
                             ^~~~
/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/php7_saxon.cpp: In function â€˜void zim_Xslt30Processor_callFunctionReturningString(zend_execute_data*, zval*)â€™:
/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/php7_saxon.cpp:1755:29: warning: NULL used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
         if(Z_TYPE_P(val) != NULL) {
                             ^~~~
/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/php7_saxon.cpp: In function â€˜void zim_Xslt30Processor_callFunctionReturningFile(zend_execute_data*, zval*)â€™:
/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/php7_saxon.cpp:1844:29: warning: NULL used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
         if(Z_TYPE_P(val) != NULL) {
                             ^~~~
/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/php7_saxon.cpp: In function â€˜void zim_Xslt30Processor_addPackages(zend_execute_data*, zval*)â€™:
/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/php7_saxon.cpp:2154:29: warning: NULL used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
         if(Z_TYPE_P(val) != NULL && Z_TYPE_P(val)== IS_STRING) {
                             ^~~~
/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/php7_saxon.cpp: In function â€˜void zim_Xslt30Processor_setInitialTemplateParameters(zend_execute_data*, zval*)â€™:
/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/php7_saxon.cpp:2207:29: warning: NULL used in arithmetic [-Wpointer-arith]
         if(Z_TYPE_P(val) != NULL) {
                             ^~~~
```

And next

```
/bin/bash /root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/libtool --mode=compile cc  -I. -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/include -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/main -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/jni  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -c /root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/SaxonCProcessor.c -o SaxonCProcessor.lo 
libtool: compile:  cc -I. -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/include -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/main -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/jni -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -g -O2 -c /root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/SaxonCProcessor.c  -fPIC -DPIC -o .libs/SaxonCProcessor.o
/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/SaxonCProcessor.c: In function â€˜xsltApplyStylesheetâ€™:
/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/SaxonCProcessor.c:191:24: warning: passing argument 1 of â€˜checkForExceptionâ€™ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     checkForException( *(environi.env), cpp);
                        ^
In file included from /root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/SaxonCProcessor.h:4:0,
                 from /root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/SaxonCProcessor.c:1:
/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/SaxonCGlue.h:214:14: note: expected â€˜sxnc_environment * {aka struct <anonymous> *}â€™ but argument is of type â€˜JNIEnv {aka const struct JNINativeInterface_ *}â€™
 const char * checkForException(sxnc_environment *environi, jobject callingObject);
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/SaxonCProcessor.c: In function â€˜executeQueryToStringâ€™:
/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/SaxonCProcessor.c:309:24: warning: passing argument 1 of â€˜checkForExceptionâ€™ from incompatible pointer type [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
     checkForException( *(environi.env), cpp);
                        ^
In file included from /root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/SaxonCProcessor.h:4:0,
                 from /root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/SaxonCProcessor.c:1:
/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/SaxonCGlue.h:214:14: note: expected â€˜sxnc_environment * {aka struct <anonymous> *}â€™ but argument is of type â€˜JNIEnv {aka const struct JNINativeInterface_ *}â€™
 const char * checkForException(sxnc_environment *environi, jobject callingObject);
              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Running `sudo make install` after that, will product next error

```
/bin/bash /root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/libtool --mode=link cc -DPHP_ATOM_INC -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/include -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/main -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API -I/usr/include/php/20151012 -I/usr/include/php/20151012/main -I/usr/include/php/20151012/TSRM -I/usr/include/php/20151012/Zend -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext -I/usr/include/php/20151012/ext/date/lib -I/root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/jni  -DHAVE_CONFIG_H  -g -O2   -o saxon.la -export-dynamic -avoid-version -prefer-pic -module -rpath /root/libsaxon/Saxonica/SaxonEEC1.2.1/Saxon.C.API/modules  php7_saxon.lo SaxonProcessor.lo XQueryProcessor.lo XsltProcessor.lo Xslt30Processor.lo XPathProcessor.lo SchemaValidator.lo XdmValue.lo XdmItem.lo XdmNode.lo XdmAtomicValue.lo SaxonCGlue.lo SaxonCProcessor.lo SaxonCXPath.lo -lstdc++ -ldl
libtool: link: cc -shared  -fPIC -DPIC  .libs/php7_saxon.o .libs/SaxonProcessor.o .libs/XQueryProcessor.o .libs/XsltProcessor.o .libs/Xslt30Processor.o .libs/XPathProcessor.o .libs/SchemaValidator.o .libs/XdmValue.o .libs/XdmItem.o .libs/XdmNode.o .libs/XdmAtomicValue.o .libs/SaxonCGlue.o .libs/SaxonCProcessor.o .libs/SaxonCXPath.o   -lstdc++ -ldl  -g -O2   -Wl,-soname -Wl,saxon.so -o .libs/saxon.so
cc: error: .libs/SchemaValidator.o: No such file or directory
Makefile:225: recipe for target 'saxon.la' failed
make: *** [saxon.la] Error 1
```

Comment: Its a strange error. I experienced the same error, but I think my disk was full so I removed some files before building again. I ran `sudo make clean` then `sudo make` and then finally `sudo make install`.  What version of PHP are you running? I am running with PHP 7.2.

Comment: I have PHP v7.3, did the same, clean and then install, still showing the build errors, but it builds successfully, so i hope it works, OS is Debian 9, thanks

Comment: Sample code from http://www.saxonica.com/saxon-c/doc1.1/html/index.html#php-api (bottom of page, last snippet) does not work, getting error Expected error: Code=Unknown Message=java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError : sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfoFile

Comment: Hi, There is a bug in the php7_saxon.cpp which is probably the cause of the build issue. Reported an issue here: https://saxonica.plan.io/issues/4400

Comment: There is a bug in the php7_saxon.cpp which is probably the cause of the build issue. The issue is logged here for resolution: saxonica.plan.io/issues/4400

Comment: This bug issue as been patched in the SaxonC 11.1 release